# Solving a Convex Optimization Problem Using a/any Programming Language

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, mathematica

I have the following convex optimization problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize}_{{f,g}} & \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} g^u{f}^{1-u}\mathrm{d}\mu\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} f \mathrm{d}\mu= 1,\quad \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} g\mathrm{d}\mu =1 \\  & f_L \leq {f} \leq f_U\\ & g_L \leq g \leq g_U\end{array}$$
where $u\in(0,1) $ and
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_L \mathrm{d}\mu< 1,\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_L \mathrm{d}\mu< 1$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_U \mathrm{d}\mu> 1,\quad\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_U \mathrm{d}\mu> 1$$
Here, $f$ and $g$ are distinct density functions, $f_L,f_U,g_L,g_U$ are some known positive functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

For illustration one can take:

$$f_L=0.8*f_{\mathcal{N}(-1,1)}$$
$$f_U=2*f_{\mathcal{N}(-1,1)}$$
$$g_L=0.8*f_{\mathcal{N}(1,1)}$$
$$g_U=2*f_{\mathcal{N}(1,1)}$$

where $f_{\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)}$ is the Gaussian density with related parameters.

> I want to solve this optimization problem but so far I have been unsuccesful. How can one solve this problem? Any programming approach is also highly appreciated. I am able to solve [the discrete version of this problem in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145191/optimization-over-vectors-with-mathematica) for up to $35$ discrete values but I was nver able solve it for the continuous case. I tried to use Matlab, Mathematica as well as CVX tool for Matlab.

Analytically I attacked this question but there are some missing points. I think probably I need to write another question for the analytical case.

Comment: You mean something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDJzG.png (blue, orange, green = $f_L$, $f_U$, $f$, computed using 101 quadrature points on $[-5,5]$)

Comment: @Rahul yes that looks nice. Exactly what I got for the discrete case when I used Binomial distributions. The functions $g,g_L,g_U$ will be the symmetric version of $f,f_L,f_U$. Especially for the cases $g_L<g<g_U$ and $f_L<f<f_U$ the densities will overlap right?

Comment: Yes, but probably only because $f_L,f_U,g_L,g_U$ are so symmetrical with each other. In other cases it does not seem to be true.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, and only for this example. Actually $u$ needs to be found minimizing the integral value. This is currently not so important. But I am honestly a bit surprised. Because, if we change $f_U=5*...$ and $g_U=5*...$ while leaving the rest same, although the problem is again symmetric, I saw in the discrete case that for $g_L<g<g_U$ and $f_L<f<f_U$, the densities do not overlap. Why it is weird? Because, if I use Lagrangians, and take derivative and make it equal to zero, $g/f$ has to be constant. Of course it doesnt necessarily mean $g/f=1$ it can be $g/f=k$ but in some cases both fails.

Comment: @Rahul could you please share your solution as an answer? I will then write another question for the analytic case and I will describe the discrepancies. Thx.

Comment: @Rahul please have a look at this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388437/solving-a-convex-optimization-problem-using-kkt-multipliers  and please post your solutions as an answer so that the other people can also see the point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with an approximation to the solution from a finite dimensional function space, then some of the software used to implement the finite element method (FEM) might be of use. This software is typically applied to solve PDEs in their weak form e.g find $u$ so that $a(u,v) = L(u)$ for all $v\in V$ where $V$ is some Hilbert space and $a$ is bilinear bounded coercive functional and $L$ is a bounded linear functional. If you can phrase your problem as equations on function spaces, then the FEM should be able to help you solve it.

In particular, I recommend [Firedrake](http://firedrakeproject.org) and [Fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/). Both have python  interfaces. To see an example of Lagrange multiplies implemented, check out [this example.](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/2016.1.0/python/demo/documented/neumann-poisson/python/documentation.html) To summarize it, solving the pure neumann Poisson's equation  requires you translate to it into a Lagrange multiplier problem and solve that using Fenics.

I will note that I see one possible flaw with this approach. I do not know how you solve a problem on the entire real line with FEM. Given your choice of example, I think that solving on a subset might require you to mess around a lot, but it could work.

Also, what exactly do you want from this? If you are looking for a precise formula, this is probably useless, but if you just want an approximation or a picture or some other quantity derived from $f$ and $g$ then this could be what you want.

Comment: In this question I am not looking for a precise formula. I will ask it tomorrow and will link it to this question. Here I am looking for a simple code (it doesnt matter which programming language, as long as I can use that language.), which will solve this problem and output a result for the one example given in the question.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören In that case I can at least recommend you take a look at FEM. The code for FEM tends not to be lots of code, but figuring out what exactly you should write might be hard.  Is your example on the entire real line too?

Comment: yes sure.. have a look at the functions $f_L,f_U,g_L,g_U$ given in the question..